# Interation on Sets using for-each loops

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, foreach

```
    @Transactional
    public Object[] cityAgents(Province province, Set<ProvinceAgents>   
                               agents,Set<ProvinceAgentDetails> details) {
          province.setCityagents(agents);
          for(ProvinceAgents agent : agents){  
              for(ProvinceAgentDetails detail :details){
                 agent.setCityagentdetails(detail);
                 detail.setAgent(agent);
              }

                 return cityDAO.saveBoth(province, agent);           
            }
          return null;      
    }


}
```

This method is from my Service with @transactional annotation.

I want to set detail for each agent. However , its setting all the details for only one agent.

Is there any way out , I can make my inner for-each loop to work for 1st user only and other time when outer loop iterates , my inner loop put details corresponding to 2nd user

Thanks for help
appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You are returning too early. Move this return to the bottom:

```
return cityDAO.saveBoth(province, agent);
```

And delete the

```
return null;
```

Unless you don't want it to return anything, at which point just change the first line to

```
cityDAO.saveBoth(province, agent);
```